# Can Mathematica Resolve this inequality?

Tags: inequalities, resolve

I want Mathematica to Indicate this inequality is (hopefully) true for all values that meet the initial conditions:

a+b+c=1 and a,b,c are positive real numbers

```
Sqrt[ab]/Sqrt[c + ab] + Sqrt[bc]/Sqrt[a + bc] + Sqrt[ac]/Sqrt[b + ac] <= 1.5
```

I tried this:

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c}, a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && a + b + c == 1, Sqrt[ab]/Sqrt[c + ab] + Sqrt[bc]/Sqrt[a + bc] + Sqrt[ac]/Sqrt[b + ac] <= 1.5], Reals]
```

But it keeps on Evaluating.Is there something that i did wrong or Mathematica is unable to resolve this?Please consider that im new to Mathematica.

Comment: @Cesareo: This results in `{0.,{a->0.333333,b->0.333333,c->0.333333}}`. so this is not it.

Comment: This result means that $1.5-\frac{\sqrt{a b}}{\sqrt{a b+c}}-\frac{\sqrt{a c}}{\sqrt{a c+b}}-\frac{\sqrt{b c}}{\sqrt{a+b c}}\ge 0$ and the equality is attained at $a=b=c=\frac 13$

Comment: @Cesareo: You deleted your comment with your suggestion to try `Minimize[{1.5-Sqrt[a*b]/Sqrt[c + a*b] + Sqrt[b*c]/Sqrt[a + b*c] + Sqrt[a*c]/Sqrt[b + a*c] ,a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && a + b + c == 1},{a,b,c}]`. You are not right that its  result does the job. Upgrade your math.

Comment: I deleted it because it wasn't understood. No need to upgrade my maths.

Comment: @Cesareo: Elaborating my comment, `{0.,{a->0.333333,b->0.333333,c->0.333333}}` means that Mathematica switches to `NMinimize` so the minimum equals zero up to a small error, the result is not exact zero.The same with the values of $a,b,c$. Math, in particular,  includes numerical analysis. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: This is a hard math inequality, likely proved by a trick. As far as I understand it, Mathematica uses standard methods to this end. That takes a lot of calculations and time and memory. Every command has its limitations.

Comment: `Resolve[ForAll[{a,b},a>0&&b>0&&1-a-b>0,Sqrt[a b]/Sqrt[c+a b]+Sqrt[b c]/Sqrt[a+b c]+Sqrt[a c]/Sqrt[b+a c]<=3/2/.c->1-a-b],Reals]`  returns True, it takes about 1 minutes on my PC.

Comment: chyanog, I see you were inspired by my answer to a shorter version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditions to reduce to two parameters to verify assumption.

```
cond1 = a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0;
cond2 = a + b + c == 1;

eq1 = Sqrt[a b]/Sqrt[c + a b] + Sqrt[b c]/Sqrt[a + b c] + 
Sqrt[a c]/Sqrt[b + a c] <= 3/2 // 
  PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> cond1] &

(*   Sqrt[(a b)/(a b + c)] + Sqrt[(a c)/(b + a c)] + 
     Sqrt[(b c)/(a + b c)] <= 3/2   *)

sol = First@Solve[cond2, c]

(*   {c -> 1 - a - b}   *)

eq2 = eq1 /. sol

(*   Sqrt[(a (1 - a - b))/(a (1 - a - b) + b)] + 
     Sqrt[(a b)/(1 - a - b + a b)] + 
     Sqrt[((1 - a - b) b)/(a + (1 - a - b) b)] <= 3/2   *)
```

Combine the two conditions

```
red1 = Reduce[cond1 /. sol, {a, b}]

(*   0 < a < 1 && 0 < b < 1 - a   *)

Resolve[ForAll[{a, b}, red1, eq2], {a, b}]

(*   True   *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Could you please explain why just solving for c and substituting works so much faster and why your code runs faster than Chyanog?

Comment: You get the same result if you just solve for a or b. I think, it works, because Reduce has to test for only two variables. Code of Chyanog seem not so fast because not simplifying with PowerExpand. Test it.